# CSS: background image opacity in ul-li menu

Tags: html, css

I have a menu using ul/li items, and they have a background image.

All over the Internet, and in stackoverflow, there is information on how to hack background image opacity. For example: https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-change-a-css-background-images-opacity

But not for my particular use case when using menus. It seems particularly tricky. From everything I have tried, one of the solutions in the aforementioned website seems to work the best.

But still, the image is not vertically aligned. I cannot seem to be able to center the image in the menu...

```css
    ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #333;
    }
    
    li {float: left;}
    
    li a {
        display: block;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    li a:hover {background-color: #4CAF50;}
    
    .my-container {
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .my-container a {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 2;
    } 
    .my-container img {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        opacity: 0.2;
    }
```

```html
    <ul>
    <li><div class="my-container"><a href="a">Aaaa</a> <img src="http://www.joaobidu.com.br/jb/content/uploads/2012/03/cancer3.png"></img></div></li>
    <li><div><a href="b">Bbbb</a></div></li>
    <li><div><a href="c">Cccc</a></div></li>
    <li><div><a href="d">Dddd</a></div></li>
    <li><div><a href="e">Eeee</a></div></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Your image is in your li and it is absolute positioned.

Comment: Is this what you're trying to do? https://jsfiddle.net/howarde/ucp33zjk/

Comment: @HowardE yes, that works perfectly in Chrome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hi,Please try this one.**

If we will use top:-14px,It will affecting the modern browser like chrome and safari which is not accepting negative values.So we can use below format for background images.

```
.my-container {
    background-image:url("http://www.joaobidu.com.br/jb/content/uploads/2012/03/cancer3.png");
    background-size:cover;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
}
```